# Tkinter window doesn't destroy after pressing Quit once, have to press Quit 4 times to close window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using the Tkinter module in python, with that I make a calculator doing the basic functions for a calculator. So there is a total of 5 different functions, using Object-oriented programming. The issue I'm having is I implement the Quit widget so it destroys the main window when pressed. But when I press it, I have to press quit a total of 4 times before the window is closed.

I would put all of my code but I'm not sure where the issue is and wanted to see any ideas you all say then ill put in the specific code.

```
self.quit = Button(self.bottom,text = 'Quit',command = self.main.destroy)
```

This is the line of code that executes to close the window using destroy.
'main' is the title of the window.
'bottom' is the fourth row.

If you require I put in all my code then I will, I just didn't want to put in 30-40 lines of code and it could be anywhere.

Is it possible since I have 5 frames, that the destroy function closes the first 3 first then finally closes the window that has quit?

Comment: The destroy command destroys a widget and all of it's children. If you're just closing a `Frame`, it won't close the window that the frame is in. Please provide a [mcve]. We definitely don't need to see your entire program, so remove all code that isn't absolutely necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Is there a specific function that closes the window, so closing everything?

Comment: The specific function is `destroy`, and you need to call it on the root window.

Comment: You do not have enough code to see why you are having to press Quit multiple times. My guess is `self.main` is not the root Tk instance.

Comment: Its honestly impossible to be sure without seeing a working example that we can test. Please provide the MCVE that Bryan linked if you want a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are a few things you could try:**

- Make sure to call `destroy()` from the root window.
- Try pressing quit once and waiting. I've had a similar problem in older machines where I'd press a button and it would take 5 whole seconds to it to respond.

Comment: destroy causes the window to stop responding and not close.